# Why didn't TinyMCE find the silver theme?

Tags: angular, tinymce

Some context.
I'm using tinymce-5.8.1 and tinymce-angular-3.6.1

This is part of my angular.json file

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myapp-dashboard",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce", "output": "/tinymce/" },
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
```

TinyMCE cannot find the silver theme, and I believe that that is the reason why it doesn't show in my app (it even ocupy space, but it is completely invisible and unusable)

[image: error on browser]

My suspicion is that my configuration is wrongly copying the files to a folder that tinymce cannot find, or tinymce is looking to the wrong place.

My questions are:

1. How can I know where tinymce is looking when it says http://localhost:4200/themes/silver/theme.js?
2. How can I know to which folder the "output": "/tinymce/"  bit is referring?

Answer (score 2):

The problem ended up being the following: for "some reason", tinymce "changes" the folders in which it looks for the skins, themes, plugins, and icons. Or maybe Angular does this. I do not know.

What I KNOW, is that an Angular application with the angular.json configuration I showed in the question, works "for a time", and suddenly "lost" access to the skins, themes, plugins, and icons.

The solution is to change the configuration of the asset to the following:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myapp-dashboard",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/skins", "output": "/skins/" },
              { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/themes", "output": "/themes/" },
              { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/plugins", "output": "/plugins/" },
              { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/icons", "output": "/icons/" },
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

Comment: While this solution worked for me (I did have to add one more line for the models folder), I don't like this solution.  I would prefer that the base_url actually work and that tinymce try to load from /tinymce than from the root.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you may have missed a step if you were following the TinyMCE Angular documentation from https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular/. In there you'll see it mentions that to load TinyMCE when the page is loaded that you should a) include the scripts configuration you've mentioned and b) to include the following settings:

```html
<editor [init]="{
  base_url: '/tinymce', // Root for resources
  suffix: '.min'        // Suffix to use when loading resources
}"></editor>
```

Without this then TinyMCE will try to load all of its resources from wherever Angular bundles or loads the `tinymce.min.js` script from. In this case that appears to be the root directory which as you've noted causes it to fail since the assets are actually in the `/tinymce/` directory.